# Upper groin hurts when riding stationary bike (Experienced cyclist)

Tags: bicycling

Not the butt or crotch area but the groin muscles, left upper inner thigh. Could be borderline hamstring.

This is really weird issue for me because I have a long background in bike racing. I no longer race but still ride a lot, do some hard group rides and play ice hockey 2-3 times a week.

I'm fit in general. I do LOADS of various leg exercises so my groin is solid for hockey. I still ride lots in the summer so my legs are still strong and I'm used to the miles. But as soon as I try to ride longer than 30 minutes on my bike in a trainer, my left groin muscles start to really bunch up.

I don't think this is a bike fit issue, this is the bike I use on the road. It's not a seat issue. Yes, there is a thick book underneath my front wheel. I stretch a decent bit so I don't think this is a flexibility issue, but maybe.

It's such an odd issue to have and I've had it for the past few years. I always assumed it was from bearing down on the seat in a weird way but I don't really feel uncomfortable. (Although all cyclists have a loose relationship with the concept of comfort.) Certainly doesn't feel different than riding on the road.

I'm just at the point where I want to try to sort it out so I can put in some solid basement miles this winter.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I would suggest seeing a PT or sports doc. We can't diagnose a long time pain, unfortunately.

Comment: Just curious .. if your left groin was hurting, on which side did you put the shim?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like its your [hip adductors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adductor_muscles_of_the_hip), which consists of several muscles that make everything tick. In regards to doing "LOADS" of leg exercises, I see guys who do a lot of by-the-science strength training, but I also see a lot of guys hanging out on isolation machines doing various things.

[image]

I raced USCF category 2 back in the day, and I'm assuming you're not talking about general pressure from the seat itself and are using normal high end cycling shorts/pants/bibs.

Personally I would ensure that I'm able to do barbell squats for my bodyweight (the weight on the bar totalling your bodyweight) comfortably with a good stance. That puts a lot of load on your adductors: if you haven't trained up your barbell squat you definitely want to start at a lighter weight and dial it up over time.

Progression wise I'd try something like this:

1. [Just your body weight squat](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Quadriceps/BWSquat.html) (3 reps of 8).
2. [Empty bar back squat](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0982522738) (45lb bar) (3 reps of 8).
3. Ramping up to at least [novice level strength standards](http://www.exrx.net/Testing/WeightLifting/SquatStandards.html). Maybe you're already at this level. If you are and have sufficient strength at this level, but are still having a problem, you're a good candidate for professional evaluation.

There's certainly nothing wrong with going and seeing a doctor or physical therapist, but I think it's a little ridiculous to imagine that every athlete that encounters anything greater than [DOMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed_onset_muscle_soreness) should go get professionally evaluated.

Comment: I do lots of squats but with minimal weight because I have some back issues. I do lots of core work but as soon as I start loading on some weight I end up getting tweaked.

Answer (score 1):

So Eric's response was excellent and thorough and appreciated. But I don't think that's the problem since I've spent a lot of effort working on sorting out my adductors/gluts and I don't run into this problem when skating or cycling outside.

The answer dawned on me the other day. My basement floor is slightly tilted and once I shimmed my trainer, I have had zero groin discomfort after riding the past two nights. Such a small little variation but I really think that's it.